# why are all share buttons not coming as a drop down list

Tags: android

Hi I am very new to android development and have gone through many questions in stack over flow but did not get any answer for this.

I want all the share intents to come as a drop down list but i get on button beside and one as a drop down list why is like this. I could explain better by sharing my screen shot but stackoverflow,com does not allow me to.

My mainactivity.java file is:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem shareItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        ShareActionProvider m=(ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
        m.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
        return true;
    }

    private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        return intent;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`

My main.xml is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_share"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       android:title="@string/action_share"
       app:showAsAction="always"
       app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
   </menu>
```

PLEASE any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last share provider is shown for the user's convenience.  If the user regularly uses the same provider, e.g. Facebook, then they can simply click on a single button to share, rather than having to drop down the list and then select it.  Of course they can drop down the list and choose a different one if they want to.

Perhaps you only have 2 share providers installed, so it looks a bit awkward.

Comment: Thanks for that, but can i disable to have the last share provider so that i can have only a drop down list?